# sorting algorithm exact case probability analysis

Tags: algorithm, sorting, probability

I'm looking at this problem for a school assignment. I can't find any material online that explains this well, so I'm looking for a general approach to problems like this. If you don't want to give the answer please give me an explanation or point me to some resources:

Assume that you are merging two sorted lists, each of size m. Note that this will use exactly 2m − 1 comparisons in the worst case (since at some point one list will become empty and the other list will not be), and exactly m comparisons in the best case.
Assume the lists are random in the following sense: You are executing Merge Sort on a random array (or more precisely a random permutation), and you are about to do a merge.

(a) What is the probability that the algorithm does exactly 2m − 1 comparisons. Justify. Simplify.

(b) What is the probability that the algorithm does exactly 2m − 2 comparisons. Justify. Simplify.

(c) What is the probability that the algorithm does exactly m comparisons. Justify. Simplify.

I don't exactly know to approach a probability problem like this. I tried to list out the exact number of arrangements but it's proven in effective. The answer I got for part a) is m!/(m^m), which I am not sure of, and I can't figure out the second part.

Comment: It's likely that the best case scenario is when the list is already sorted, and the worst case is when the list is sorted completely backwards.  [What are the odds that a random array is already sorted?](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/14209/probability-that-a-uniformly-random-sequence-is-already-sorted)

Comment: "Assume that you are merging two sorted list"

Comment: Ah.  Well that's way over my head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's call the two lists you're merging A and B. And just to be clear, let's assume that the sort order is ascending, and without loss of generality, let's say that the merged arrays contain the numbers 1, 2, 3, ..., 2m. And to be precise, we'll assume that "random permutation" means "all permutations are equally likely".

If one of the lists (B, say) is left with k elements when A is exhausted, then it must be that B[m-k] is larger than everything in A. Since B is sorted, B must hold the largest k numbers from 1, 2, ..., 2m. And not the (k+1)st largest number otherwise B would be left with at least k+1 elements when A is exhausted.

How many possibilities is that? Well, A must contain 2m-k, and any (sorted) subset of size m-1 of the lowest 2m-k-1 numbers. That's (2m-k-1) choose (m-1).

There are (2m choose m) possibilities in general for A and B, so overall the probability that there's k elements left in B after merging is (2m-k-1 choose m-1) / (2m choose m).

The probability that that there's k>0 elements left in either A or B is double that.

If there's k elements left in A or B, the total number of comparisons will be 2m-k. So we're in a position to answer your question:

- (a) 2m-1 comparisons: k=1, so the probability is 2(2m-2 choose m-1) / (2m choose m) = m / (2m - 1).
- (b) 2m-2 comparisons: k=2, so the probability is 2(2m-3 choose m-1) / (2m choose m) = m / (4m - 2).
- (c) m comparisons: k=m, so the probability is 2(m-1 choose m-1) / (2m choose m) = 2 / (2m choose m).

Or some quick reasoning that doesn't go through the general case:

- (a) 2m-1 comparisons occur when 2m and 2m-1 appear in different arrays. 2m appears in one array, and so there's m / (2m - 1) chance it appears in the other.
- (b) 2m-2 comparisons occur when 2m and 2m-1 appear in the same array, and 2m-2 in the other. That happens with probability (m-1)(2m-1) * m/(2m-2) = m / 2(2m-1).
- (c) m comparisons occur when the m largest numbers appear in the same array. There's only two possibilities for that (either A or B must contain the numbers m+1, ..., 2m), and there's (2m choose m) ways in general of picking A and B, so the probability is 2/(2m choose m).

Comment: This is extremely helpful. Very explicit clarification, thank you so much.